# Bug in PHP & Buster? 4x Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode 0x00000004

Tags: kernel, php, corrupt

I have 2 exact the same Pi's: both are Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2.

Both were running Raspbian Stretch for years. 4 days ago **both Pi's (!!!)** had a Kernel Panic after trying to update to php7.4. Installs were **very** old so I did not bother spending a lot of time: I decided to a full re-install of the `2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-lite`.

**Note**: I corrupted both Pi's **at the same time**, they both had an old SDHC card, one of 4 GB and the other 8 GB.

So I started with new cards, MircoSD this time:

1. The first has a 16 GB disk MicroSD in an adapter
2. The other has a 32 GB disk MicroSD in an adapter

I installed Buster, all went well. Wifi, openssh etc etc.

Then I tried PHP8, but it would not start Apache.
Removed PHP8, naked install of Apache - all went OK.

Then install PHP7.4, following this page: https://vitux.com/debian-php-installation/

Apache would not start. Tried to fix. Then:

```
apt update

apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then command line said ILLEGAL INSTRUCTION at every key I hit.

Reboot...

`Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode 0x00000004`, On both my Raspberry's at exact the same time.

Is there a bug in the combo Raspbian / Buster and PHP 7.4?
Any solution here?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository you are using is not supporting ARMv6, so you'll need at least Pi 2 to run packages from it. See the following issues on their tracker:

https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1167

https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1172

Comment: Now that is very helpful info. Going to check it out. Thanks a lot! I hope my post helps others too, I won't be the first (nor last) tinkerer to experience this.

Comment: @Adriaan If the answer helped you to solve your problem then please mark it as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.